# The Name 'CommonFolderQuery' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to get music files from Windows Phone 8.1 and I want to group them by Artist. I am following this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127).

```
// To get all music folders present in Music library
IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> MusicFolders = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByArtist);
```

But this error is shown. What could be the reason? Did I miss a using directive or an assembly reference??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CommonFolderQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207957) enumeration is located in the `Windows.Storage.Search` namespace.

Make sure you've included a `using` directive at the top of your file:

```
using Windows.Storage.Search;
```